# Windows equivalent of whereis?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there an equivalent of the Unix [whereis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whereis) command in Windows?

So that I could figure out where commands I can run actually is.

Comment: I think for the sake of seacheability it would make sense to inculde `type` and `which` in the question title, along with `whereis` which I personally used only occasionally. `type` is a popular Bash built-in and `which` is a variant of `whereis` restricted to searching commands (`whereis` can also search for `man` pages and the like).

Answer (score 297, accepted):

The **where** command does what you want and goes back at least to the resource kit for Windows 98, and is included by default in Server 2003, Vista, and newer:

```
C:\>where csc
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
```

If executed with no arguments (on Vista), it results in one of my favorite messages:

```
C:\>where
ERROR: The operation completed successfully.
```

If executing in PowerShell, be sure to include '.exe' to distinguish from any 'where' aliases or scripts along the path. ('where' is a typical alias for Where-Object.ps1)

```
C:\> where.exe where.exe
C:\Windows\System32\where.exe
```

Comment: Everyday I learn something new...

Comment: Kind of sad `where` just returns usage help now in Windows 7. Wanted to see it for myself :p

Comment: `where` not available in XP

Comment: @TomRoggero, I could have been more clear. It's part of the optional resource kit starting with Windows 98, and only included in the base install for version after XP.

Comment: For anyone searching for this with windows 10:
you are looking for `Get-Command`, or `gcm` in the powershell, and don't try it without arguments

Comment: With powershell type where.exe ssh instead of just where.

Comment: Note that in batch files you can use `WHERE` together with `/Q` so you can check its errorlevel ... e.g. `WHERE /Q npm.cmd & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Not Found`. This more flexible than `IF EXISTS path ...`, because it can find every occurrence that is specified by `PATH` with just one query.

Answer (score 25):

You can run the following PowerShell command:

`gcm <command>`

[Get-Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-7.2)

> The Get-Command cmdlet gets all commands that are installed on the computer, including cmdlets, aliases, functions, filters, scripts, and applications. Get-Command gets the commands from PowerShell modules and commands that were imported from other sessions. To get only commands that have been imported into the current session, use the ListImported parameter.

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't recognize gcm: `"'gcm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."`

Comment: This is a powershell command, must be run from a powershell prompt, not from cmd.exe

Answer (score 14):

Please, use **where** command:

```
> where app.exe
```

It is the best way to achieve your goal.

You can also use PowerShell command:

```
> $env:path.Split(';') | gci -Filter app.exe
```

and expanded version looks like this:

```
 > $env:path.Split(';') | select -Unique | ? {$_ -and (test-path $_)} | gci -Filter app.exe
```

Answer (score 7):

hackerish which.cmd:

```
@echo off
@set PATH=.;%PATH%

@rem 
@rem about:  something similar like the unix-alike-which, but with
@rem         within pure cmd
@rem 

if "%1" == "" (
    @echo Usage: 
    @echo.
    @echo   which 'cmd'
    @echo.
    @echo.if 'cmd' is not found, ERRORLEVEL is set to 1
    @echo.  
) else (
    ( @for %%f in (%1 %1.exe %1.cmd %1.bat %1.pif) do if not "%%~$PATH:f" == "" ( @echo %%~$PATH:f ) else @set ERRORLEVEL=1) 
)
```

Comment: This is a good fix for older systems, but you should know that it results in a few quirks.  It matches directories, only returns the first result found in the path for each extension, and should include every extension found in the PATHEXT environment variable.

Comment: yah, this is a bit older hack of mine, when i pasted it here i instantly saw the potential for %PATHEXT% :)

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere "out there" I found this batch file `whereis.bat`:

```
@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in (%1%%e) do @if NOT "%%~$PATH:i"=="" echo %%~$PATH:i
```

Update: maybe I found it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/76965/find-out-which-application-is-running-when-started-from-windows-command-prompt/76968#76968).

Comment: With modern Windows (10/11), you can achieve the same via `WHERE %1`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the **where** command on windows 10, in cmd, I used the following command to recursively search c drive for copies of the c# compiler, `csc.exe`.

```
c:\> where /r c:\ csc.exe
```

Sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is at least a [Windows port](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) for the `which` utility.

Comment: or you can use `WHERE` in Windows 10/11 ...

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this today and since I'm on XP without the resource kit, I turned to powershell with the following command:

```
dir -path c:\ -filter ffmpeg.* -r
```

Comment: I'm not proficient in powershell but it seems you're searching through the whole directory tree. This is not equivalent to `where` which only searches in the `%PATH%`. Moreover it's much slower and gives errors for folders you don't have read permission

Comment: Agreed... I did not require an exact copy of the functionality, just the ability to locate a program.

Answer (score 1):

```
function find ($string) { 
   Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\' -Recurse -Filter $string; 
}

function whereis ($string) { 
   $superpath = "$env:Path;C:\Program Files;C:\Program Files (x86)";
   (echo $superpath).Split(';') | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter $string; 
}
```

Example:

PS >find Mozilla.admx

```
    Directory: C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions                                                                                     

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                           
-a----        1/27/2016  12:22 PM          37146 Mozilla.admx
```

PS >whereis firefox.exe

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox                                                                                 

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                           
-a----        9/21/2017   5:30 PM         477136 firefox.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

**which.cmd**

```
@echo off

if "%~1" equ "" (
    echo usage: %~n0 [command] & exit /b 0
) else where $Path:%1 2>nul || (
    echo | set /p x=%~n0: no '%1' in & path
)
```

**doskey.exe**

```
doskey which=where $1 2$Gnul
```

**Usage:**

```
> which.cmd git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

> which.cmd foo
which: no 'foo' in PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Win
dows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try searching for the command using the following:

```
dir /s type-whatever-you-are-searching
```

Comment: This does not work for me. For example, the exp command is in my path, but dir/s exp or dir /s exp.exe just gives "File Not Found".

Comment: This would work if a) you search from the root of the drive, b) your path is all on one drive, and c) your path is in lexicographical order.  Even under these conditions it will be ridiculously slow.