# "which" for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-vista, which

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows equivalent of whereis?](https://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis)

I'm used to saying "which foo" on Unix systems to see what's going to run.

Today I'm having trouble with a program on Windows, and I think it may be the wrong command that's running.  How do I determine, from cmd.exe, what program it's actually going to run when I type "foo"?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis/39260#39260

Comment: akira: Great find!  (I was having trouble getting SU to believe that I wanted to find the word "which".)  Can I bless a comment into an answer?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, using your "foo" example, typing

```
foo /?
```

That should do similar on windows as adding --help does in linux. Not always, mind you, but it should let you know exactly what's going on, as well as some command syntax.

Comment: But running foo /? doesn't show which directory it is running from, only how to run it, which is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @steve.lippert .. true, but getting the usage back often indicates *something* about the program itself - though maybe not enough in all cases

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case it's a command that has no visible output, or gives a generic error message.  From `/?` (and any other flags I can think up) I can't tell exactly which one it's running.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a 'which' for Windows, but from the command line you can run [path](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/path.mspx?mfr=true) to see where it is looking for the files.  I believe it searches the path in order and will run the first executable it finds.

Remember that CMD.EXE will also search the local directory for a program to run and I believe this takes precedence.

Comment: I thought I've heard that `cmd.exe` has some special cases that aren't in `%PATH%`, which is why I'm asking.  Plus I don't love the idea of hunting through all of the paths myself.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [steve](https://superuser.com/users/10581/steve-lippert)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/164507/which-for-windows/164513#164513), from `%SYSTEM_ROOT%` you can run an `attrib` search to see where 'foo' lives, then compare to the %PATH% to see which would execute first:

```
attrib /s foo.exe
...
echo %PATH%
```

Comment: Good to know! But the variable is %systemroot%.  cd %systemroot%, attrib /s ping.exe

Comment: -1: `attrib /s foo.exe` just searches the current directory and all subdirectories for foo.exe. (You could do the same thing with `dir /a-d /s /b foo.exe` or Win+F.) On my computer, %SYSTEMROOT% is C:\WINDOWS, so you're really just searching in that directory and below. You could `cd \ ` first, or use Win+F to search for foo.exe, but those preform really long searches, when you really just need to search the path.

Answer (score 0):

The which that comes with Cygwin (http://cygwin.org) will run from cmd.exe and probably do what you want otherwise. Be aware that if you're looking for a .bat, you need to explicitly add the .bat, e.g., "which gorp.bat" will find gorp.bat, but "which gorp" will not.

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately this is a server which doesn't have Cygwin, and I'm not sure they want me installing Cygwin there.