# How can you find out where an executable is resolved from on the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows equivalent of whereis?](https://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis)

On the command line in Windows you can type the name of an executable (ex. ipconfig) and it will look attempt to resolve the path to that executable by looking for it in the folders specified in your PATH environment setting.

I'm wondering how to find out where Windows found the executable. In my example, I want to know where it found and executed 'ipconfig' from.

Is there a command to find this out? Something like 'resolve ipconfig' and it would return 'C:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe'?

Comment: Exact duplicate (using different wording): http://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a version of where.exe that will do just this that is included with Visual Studio and is available from sites online if you go looking. Easy to use and no need for the full cygwin suite (or even part of it).

Answer (score 0):

Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).  In the Bash shell, type

```
which <command>
```