# Why find.exe not work in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

My find.exe in Windows 7 can not find anything.

> C:\topo\server\bin>echo "hello" | find
>   "h"
>
> C:\topo\server\bin>

I copied a find.exe from Windows XP, doesn't work too.

Comment: Interesting. I wish I could test this myself. Vista's search was broken for a while after its initial launch - maybe something similar happened with Win7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I find the answer, because I set the code page of the cmd.exe to 65001(UTF-8), after I change back the code page , the find works ok.

So, It's another question, why find not work after change code page. I will ask it in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Windows searches the current directory first. Is there a `find` program in `C:\topo\server\bin`?

Use the [where](https://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis) command to find out which `find` command you're invoking.

If you have Cygwin or other unix/posix utility suite installed, remember that it contains a completely different `find` command.

Comment: I am sure the find.exe is in c:\windows\system32