# How do I permantly set the command-prompt codepage in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I would like to set permantly in DOS the codepage.

```
chcp 1252
```

How can I store the result of that command?

Comment: Also see: [Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](http://superuser.com/q/269818/3094)

Answer (score 10):

Open the registry editor (`regedit`) and navigate to the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
```

Edit the `OEMCP` value on the right and change it from the default (*861*?) to *1252*.

Now open a new command-prompt and type `chcp` to see the current codepage. (It may—probably?—will not take until you reboot.)

---

Another way you can do it is to add the `chcp` command to the `Autorun` key (you can set it for either a specific user or the whole system):

```
REGEDIT4

; Auto–code-page.reg
; Have chcp automatically run whenever a command-prompt is opened
;

;For current user
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"="chcp 1252"

;For all users
;[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
;"Autorun"="chcp 1252"
```

Comment: On my German win7 system the default code page was 850.

Comment: @Christian, yes, it will vary depending on the Windows language used. However, with nothing more to go on than the OP’s name, I suspect they are most likely using code-page 861 by default.

Answer (score 6):

Open Control Panel. Choose *Clock, Language and Region*:

[image]

Then *Change keyboard or other input methods*:

[image]

Switch to the *Administrative* tab:

[image]

Click *Change system locale* under *Language for non-Unicode programs* and choose the desired language.

But yes, it changes:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\OEMCP
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\ACP
```

and maybe other things.

Speaking of which, that's probably why changing `OEMCP` to `65001` made the system [unbootable](https://superuser.com/a/678590/185665). There's no such option in Control Panel.

(*Screenshots taken from [here](https://www.coscom.co.jp/learnjapanese801/japanesefont/nonunicode_win7.html) as I don't have Windows with an English language pack at hand to make screenshots.*)

Answer (score 3):

Changing the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage` makes my system unable to boot.

Adding a string value in 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` of

```
"Autorun"="chcp 1252"
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a user of Russian-localized Windows 7 x64 and so I need to set Code Page 1251 (Windows Cyrillic) as the default for CMD. The [solution by Synetech](https://superuser.com/a/387574/71768) as well as the [solution by Steven Penny](https://superuser.com/a/927575/71768) do work but with the latter only CMD will be affected and so for example the `ping` utility will work incorrectly, so I decided to apply them both. At the same time changing default Code Page isn't sufficient: the default font of the CMD window does not support this encoding and I'm forced to set the `Lucida Console` font as the default. The following .REG file does the whole work (changing the default codepage to 1251 and also setting `Lucida Console` as the default font for CMD with proper properties):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
"OEMCP"="1251"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
; Code Page 1251
"CodePage"=dword:000004e3
; Default font for CMD window is "Lucida Console"
"FaceName"="Lucida Console"
"FontFamily"=dword:00000036
"FontSize"=dword:00140000
"FontWeight"=dword:00000190
"ScreenBufferSize"=dword:012C0064
"WindowSize"=dword:00190064
```

After importing this .REG file into the registry (by double-clicking on the file and choosing "Yes") you must reboot the system for the changes to take effect.