# How do I view unicode characters on command prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, encoding, unicode

I read this [*post on superuser*](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8) on how to view `UTF-8` characters on command prompt in windows. I tried the steps in the answer which were :

1. `Start -> Run -> regedit`
2. Go to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun]`
3. Change the value to `chcp 65001`

I reach *Command Processor* but then I do not see *Autorun* . 
I have added a screenshot of that :

[image]

What do I do now ? The font I have selected for `cmd` is `Lucida Console`. I want to see the Unicode characters on the command prompt. Like I have to test some programs that contains Urdu text. 
I get question marks or some other sort of text in place of the original one.

> **Note**: I am using a 32-bit OS

Comment: Check Jukka's answer below, then if the chcp command and selected font works from the command-line, try adding the *Autorun* sub-key and then modifying its value.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer you quoted has an error: the code page number for UTF-8 in Windows is 65001, not 6500. You should test things first by just setting `chcp 65001` in the console window; the question cited is just about making this setting the default by making Windows execute it automatically.

To see Urdu text, you need to select a font that contains the Arabic letters used in Urdu. Lucida Console does not contain Arabic letters. I would expect that checking for [font support to the letter PEH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/67e/fontsupport.htm) is suitable. Among the alternatives that are commonly available, Courier New is the only monospace font – but Arabic writing isn’t that suitable for monospace rendering, so consider using e.g. Arial, unless you have a special reason to use a monospace font.

Comment: Just edited the other post, wonder how come no one caught the error till now!

Comment: Also noticed that command-line on my windows 7 64 bit doesn't require autorun to have unicode, I see unicode characters right after selecting Lucida Console as the font. So probably just Arabic support is the only problem

Answer (score 2):

There is a better answer on same page by [Steven Penny](https://superuser.com/a/927575/248914):

```
REG ADD HKCU\Console /v CodePage /t REG_DWORD /d 0xfde9
```

just execute above code from anywhere in windows(for example in cmd or in run) just for one time and your code-page on cmd will be changed to 65001 forever.