# 7-zip unzipping files via command line where the zip contains special characters

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, special-characters

7-zip was used in Windows to compress a batch of folders that contained file paths and file names that uses special characters such as € and accented letters.

When the command line prompt is used to unzip, files will go from (as an example) België.tif to Belgi#U00eb.tif

Does anyone know of a way to extract without losing the special character?

Comment: maybe the windows machine where you are doing the extraction doesn't support such special characters?

Comment: Hello, if you are talking about command line, please at minimum show the exact command you're running. Remember that questions should be **as specific as possible**.

Comment: Are you trying to create that folder ( like when right click > 7z > "Extract to *" )?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it on Windows 10 22H2. Files within the archive are being written with their full name ( "unnamedë.png" ). I couldn't find a command to create a new folder. I used '7z.exe x asd.7z"

Comment: @SparedWhisle it's extracting to a server machine and when I log in via the FTP, I can manually rename the file to the special character, so the machine where it's being extracted to definitely does support it.

Comment: @Destroy666 sorry! I'm actually the one zipping the files using Windows 11, and the person on the other side is unzipping the files to the server. I've asked him a few times to see what the command line he's using but he hasn't responded so I'm trying to just find out what currently exists out there so that I can help him extract the files correctly.

Comment: Are the same versions of 7-Zip used at both ends? Have you tried unzipping on the *same* PC that created them?

Comment: Ok. Ask them also about: their system, 7-zip version and if it happens if they unzip some other archives that contain files/dirs with special characters.

Comment: They likely do not use 7-Zip... In that case, just have them try with 7-Zip

Comment: _p7zip_ has limitations regarding Unicode. What’s the value of the `LANG` and `LC_CTYPE` environment variables on the system extracting the archive?

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode character
[U+00eb](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00EB)
is correct and is indeed the character `ë`,
so it seems that everything is working right.

I would guess that the person that is viewing the extracted files
uses a wrong method of displaying the names, either using a utility
that does not support Unicode, or uses CMD with a code-page that
doesn't support UTF8.

For the later case, see the post
[Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8).