# 'which' equivalent in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, mac, which

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows equivalent of whereis?](https://superuser.com/questions/21067)

For Linux/Mac I can use [`which`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_%28Unix%29) to locate the file. What would be the equivalent to this command line tool of `which`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's `WHERE` to find any files in your path.

On XP/2003 and earlier, you need to add it from the Resource Kit, but it a standard command in Vista onwards.

Comment: By the way, `where | clip` will put the path into the clipboard, which is useful.

Comment: Use `where.exe` in Windows PowerShell otherwise it conflicts with the built-in `where` command. To use `which` in PS, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell