# How can I "which <binary>" in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, which

Is there a way to quickly determine where a binary (that the `%PATH%` variable points to) is located.

That is something that would do the equivalent of `which perl` in a traditional unix shell.

I understand that [The resource Kit](https://superuser.com/questions/199125/which-equivalent-in-windows) has a `where` command, but this kit is not installed on my (corporate)-computer, so I cannot use `where`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A cmd.exe one-liner for `which` would be:

```
for %G in (<binary.exe>) do @echo.%~$PATH:G
```

You can code it as a simple which.bat:

```
@echo off
for %%G in (%1) do @echo.%%~$PATH:G
```

EDIT: it requires full name of binary: `which perl.exe`, not `which perl`.
It is possible to write a batch file that takes %PATHEXT% into consideration, so it does not need the full name of binary. Please let me know if you need it.

EDIT2: anyway I decided to write the batch file. Here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ext= ;%PATHEXT%
:extloop1
for /f "delims=; tokens=1,*" %%A in ("!ext!") do (
  if exist %1%%A (
    echo .\%1%%A
    goto finish
  )
  set ext=%%B
)
if "!ext!" neq "" goto extloop1

set ext= ;%PATHEXT%
:extloop2
for /f "delims=; tokens=1,*" %%A in ("!ext!") do (
  for %%C in (%1%%A) do (
    if exist %%~$PATH:C (
      echo %%~$PATH:C
      goto finish
    )
  )
  set ext=%%B
)
if "!ext!" neq "" goto extloop2

:finish
endlocal
```

First, as per Bob's sugestion, it checks if the binary exists in the current directory. If the binary is not found, another loop is executed which does the search through %PATH% variable.

Loops are based on `if ... goto`, `for` command is used only to split the `ext` value by ';' character. The value of `%PATHEXT%` is prepended with an empty extension, which allows for searching for fully named binary - both `which perl` and `which perl.exe` works.

Comment: Well, if you do end up writing an extended batch file, might as well go all the way and check `.\binary.*` first. [*The operating system always searches in the current directory first, before it searches the directories in the command path.*](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/path.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 3):

You could try Paul Sadowski's collection of utilities - he includes a `which`. See it at: http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cmdprogs.htm