# Determine the path of an executed program on Windows

Tags: windows, path, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows equivalent of whereis?](https://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis)

I know that you can open the task manager and right-click on a process and select "Open file path".

But what can I do if the program is just a console application which closes right after its start?

Actually, I want to update my GNU Make but I want to know where it is installed.

Comment: In your particular place, try [one of the suggestions here](http://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis). You want to find the path of this program, which you execute by typing `make` in the command line (I assume). That means it must be somewhere in one of the paths in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: @akira Beat me to it :P

Comment: @akira, @bob: Thanks, `where` also works and is more comfortable than the Process Explorer!  I have a very long `PATH` so I didn't want to search there ;) But maybe I can integrate this functionality into my  app which already displays a GUI for changing the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) by Microsoft (Sysinternals). There you are able to pause the current process view via <kbd>space</kbd>, hence you can determine where the process path of the program is.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I had to set the update speed to 5 seconds ;)