# I've launched a .cmd file from somewhere in my %PATH% How can I know the location of the file?

Tags: windows

I can successfully run a .cmd file by typing its name (`tsc` in this case):

```
C:\Windows\system32>tsc --version
Version 1.0.3.0
```

It instantly prints the result and terminates.

There is no `tsc` in C:\Windows\system32, so presumably it is being launched somewhere from a location specified in my %PATH%. I've searched through the drive and found a bunch of `tsc.cmd` files. How can I know, which of them is being launched?

Related, probably a duplicate: [Windows equivalent of whereis?](https://superuser.com/questions/21067/)

Comment: Perhaps you can find something in the Event Viewer related to applications or system

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`where` command](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) in `cmd` will tell you what you want to know:

```
where tsc.cmd
```

In this basic invocation it is the equivalent of the Unix `which`, though `where` has additional options not in the Unix command.

Comment: I used `where` in Linux, but had no idea there was a Windows analogue!

Comment: It was introduced in Windows 2003, so it's not in XP, where many of us became familiar with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Install
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Double-click on the `tsc` process will give all the information you need.

[image]

Comment: There is no `tsc` process, it is a .cmd file. It also terminates instantly.